# Why Chrome send the certificate only after IE sent it first?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, internet-explorer, web-applications, certificate

I have an application where users can authenticate with certificates. In front of the application server i have an apache server that request and verify the certificates. 
My problem is that the Chrome browser wont let me chose the certificate i want to use and wont send it. In IE the popup appears and i can select the certificate and the certificate is sent.
The strangest thing is that after i send the certificate in IE one time, on all the future requests Chrome also send it.
Why Chrome send the certificate only after IE send it first?

In my apache coniguration i have SSLCACertificateFile set with the CA certificate and SSLVerifyClient optional SSLVerifyDepth 2

Comment: Did you set the apache client authentication as mandatory? have you set up the CA trusted list? Please, include in your question your apache SSL config. The relationship between Chrome and IE does not make sense

Comment: In this moment i cant test with SSLVerifyClient required. I will post the result later. For me is strange that in this configuration it has this behaviour.

Comment: `SSLVerifyClient optional` means the browser may present a certificate but it is not mandatory. Chrome/IE should show to select the certificates whose issuer is in `SSLCACertificateFile`. If you want that the browser always prompt user for a certificate, then use `SSLVerifyClient required`

Comment: It seems that the problem was with `SSLVerifyClient optional`. It should be  
`SSLVerifyClient required`. Initially the requirements were that the certificate authentication should be optional. The client could present a certificate or not. This requirement is not longer nedded and I forgot `SSLVerifyClient optional` setting in apache. Thank you!